# Label Not Showing in Odoo-9

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-9

I created a boolean field. The boolean is showing but the label isn't.

```
class product_pricelist_inherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.pricelist'

    myfield= fields.Boolean(string="Is this Pricelist Eligible for Me?")
```

XML:

```
<odoo>
  <record id="product_product_pricelist_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="model">product.pricelist</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_pricelist_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="name" position="after">
          <field name="myfield"/>
        </field>
    </field>
  </record>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not show your field label because you have added field in `<div>`

Try with following code.

Replace

```
<field name="myfield"/>
```

with

```
<label for="myfield"/>
<field name="myfield"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `group` to show field label:

```
<group>
    <field name="myfield"/>
</group>
```

There is a `group` just after `name` field, It can be done using `xpath`:

```
<xpath expr="//group" position="inside">
    <field name="myfield"/>
</xpath>
```

For the first example you can use `position="before"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your field inside group:

```
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <group name="example_group"  position="inside">
                        <field name="your_field" />
                </group>
        </field>
```